# Sending HTTP POST data with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, http-post

I have some code that uses POST to send an image. What I want to do is send some text along in the same post. This is what I have so far:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *photoRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoPostString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[photoRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[photoRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", obsID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[photoRequest setHTTPBody:body];
```

This works in that the image is sent and received by the URL. What I want to do is send some other information - the photoID for example - as a string and within the same request. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect, just add following code below your code to send other data like text.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:@"<YOUR TEXT>" forKey:@"<KEY>"];

    [body appendData:[self createFormData:dict withBoundary:boundary]];
    [photoRequest setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:photoRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

And here is the function to create form data.

```
- (NSData*)createFormData:(NSDictionary*)myDictionary withBoundary:(NSString*)myBounds
{
    NSMutableData *myReturn = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSArray *formKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    for (int i = 0; i < [formKeys count]; i++) {
        [myReturn appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",myBounds] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [myReturn appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%@",[formKeys objectAtIndex:i],[myDictionary valueForKey:[formKeys objectAtIndex:i]]] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }
    return myReturn;
}
```

Comment: This worked ... but I am not sure why this did and the other answer didn't. On a supplementary (as it had be baffled for hours) when you do the returnData returnString part it didn't seem to like it when I used print $query in the php and always returned "null" to Xcode. No problem with a string such as print "image loaded". I was trying to see what the query was but I never could. Is that normal?

Comment: The problem is with text??. If yes than can you show me which text are you passing? May be needs to encode that text if you enter spacial characters or emojis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Have a try.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *photoRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoPostString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[photoRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[photoRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", obsID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"photoID=1234" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[photoRequest setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: This didn't work but the other answer did. I am not sure of the reason as they seem to imply the same.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Updated.